# Google sheets how to pull any DATA under a column with that field

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to pull certain data from the entire sheet here is a quick example

| DATE | TIME | TICKET# |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/23/2024 | 1PM | 444444 |

| DATE | TIME | TICKET# |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12/23/2024 | 2PM | 444433 |

What I am trying to accomplish is that I want to create a separate sheet so that I can now write if any column = date, for example, that I can grab the data in the row below date I don't care what data is under meaning no need to verify

The thing is one column there are multiple rows containing date time and ticket.

[Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rYv9yffCLB33L4IR5ncAnXwh1M1z1uj6txqggQl9D8k/edit#gid=0) to my example sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `FILTER` function:

```cpp
=FILTER(Sheet1!A2:ZZZ,Sheet1!1:1=A1)
```

This formula assumes your dates are in Sheet1 row 1 and A1 is the given date.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rYv9yffCLB33L4IR5ncAnXwh1M1z1uj6txqggQl9D8k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: For the sake of saving time I made some mock data but notice how there are multiple dates and time and company name since there is a lot of unneeded data I just need to create a seperate area that only grabs what I ask

Comment: where is the input and where should the expected output be?

Comment: There is an area on the right hand side that I separated by a black bar it contains field like these Date Time Ticket # Person Company name

Comment: so you want the output in H2:L2? What about the input? Where is the input date?

Comment: also, please provide edit access. Right now the sheet is view only.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rYv9yffCLB33L4IR5ncAnXwh1M1z1uj6txqggQl9D8k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Also the data is on the left side lets say A1:D18

Comment: The reason range is so large is because time or ticket number may exists in those sheets